# Problem with Open method of MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 PATCH request

Tags: vba, msxml6

I have been using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 successfully with my Excel VBA script for a couple years, for both GET and POST requests.  The POST request looks like:

```
Dim zipService as Object
Dim Query As String
Dim Body As String
Set zipService = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
Query = "https://10.xxx.xxx.xxx:443/api/rest/v1/bulk/thresholdRules/"
zipService.Open "POST", Query, False
zipService.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & gsUserIDPW
zipService.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"     
zipService.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"       
Body = "Body of the request"
zipService.send (sBody)
```

Now I need to need to make a PATCH request to a new REST call for the same API. I have tested the PATCH REST call in Postman, and it works successfully.  Using PUT in Postman also works.  However, in Excel, when I try to do the Open call using PATCH (or PUT), the Open call fails with a -2147012891 error.

Any suggestions?  Are PATCH and PUT allowed with the Open method?  Are there other parameters I have to specify?  All the code examples I find online are always GET and POST requests.

Comment: -2147012891 = &h80072ee5 = 12005 = ERROR_INTERNET_INVALID_URL              (INTERNET_ERROR_BASE + 5)

Comment: Thanks! What resource did you use to look up the -2147012891?  I had trouble finding it myself.  I was fixated on the MSXML2 object, when the real problem was in my query string.

Comment: It is in WinINet.h header file. There is a list here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/wininet-errors. See decoding errors https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/decoding-errors.html. The headers are here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/